# Symfony 2 form events

Tags: php, forms, symfony, pagination

I am setting up a test site with symfony and I built a datagrid with pagination that works correctly.

One standard feature I would like to add to pagination is the number of displayed items to be set for a dropdown menu:

I have a choice field (for the moment in a controller, but later I will put it in a form class.)

Form with the choice field in built using this code:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            // ->setAction($this->generateUrl('userlist2'))
            //->setMethod('GET')
            ->add('numRecords', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('5' => '5', '10' => '10', '20' => '20'),
                'required' => false,
                'empty_value' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'style' => 'width:80px',
                )
                    )
            )
            ->getForm();
```

I have googled to check if symfony has a way to get changes in choice field but could not find it.

What I need is to intercept the change event of the choice field and get its value, so I can put the item number value in a variable and use it for pagination.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Paolo

Comment: you mean something like, as soon as the value changes client side, you want to 'reformat' your view?

Comment: you have to manually add listeners to it using javascript or easier yet jquery.